# Embed datepicker inside an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, datepicker

I want to embed a `DatePickerDialog` inside an Android activity itself. I do not want the `DatePicker` to appear when clicked on a button as a dialog but embed it inside my activity itself. I have tried using the `DatePicker` view inside my layout, but this seems to be different from `DatePickerDialog`.

I am using `DialogFragment` for creating the `DatePickerDialog` and using the following code in `onCreate` of `MainAcitivity.java`

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    DatePickerDialogFragment datePickerDialogFragment = DatePickerDialogFragment.newInstance();

    ft.add(R.id.main_screen_layout, datePickerDialogFragment); // main_screen_layout is given as the id for the layout related to MainActivity
    ft.commit();
```

// DatePickerDialogFragment.java

`public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment`

```
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

public static DatePickerDialogFragment newInstance() {
    return new DatePickerDialogFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_datepicker, container, false);
    View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.tv);

    ((TextView)tv).setText("This is a new instance");

    return v;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, 
            c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

`}`

How to go about this?

Comment: There're lot of date pickers UI components. Why you do not use one of these?

Answer (score 1):

I've DatePicker and DateTime within the activity layout. The idea is to allow the edition of both, compose a date time value and return it once the user clicks on a done/set button. 
Below, you can find some code showing how the DatePicker is embedded into the layout and the activity code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />
</LinearLayout>


public class DateSelectionActivity extends Activity {

    private DatePicker datePicker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ...

        this.datePicker = (DatePicker) this.findViewById(R.id.date_value);
        this.datePicker.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), null);

        // ...
    }

    private OnClickListener confirmButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Get user selection
                // DateSelectionActivity.this.datePicker.getYear());
                // DateSelectionActivity.this.datePicker.getMonth());
                // DateSelectionActivity.this.datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
            }
    }
}
```